# How to refresh NumericUpDown on Leave

Tags: vb.net

I have NumericUpDown control to show numbers with 2 Decimal places.
If I type in 0,156 after leave it will show 0,16. If I type 0 after leaving there will be 0,00 just as expected.
But if I delete all the content of NumericUpDown (SelectAll+Delete) and then navigate from this control it will not show 0,00. Instead it will stay blank!

How to get 0 in specified format into a NumericUpDown after leaving it if I delete all the content of it?

Comment: Hmmm... you want to do something when you leave a control.  If only there was an event that was specific to when you leave a control.

Comment: Subscribe to Leave or LostFocus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching and experimenting I find an answer by myself.

```
    Private Sub NumericUpDown1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown1.Leave

        Dim Val As Decimal = 0
        If Decimal.TryParse(NumericUpDown1.Text, Val) = 0 Then
            NumericUpDown1.Value = 0
            NumericUpDown1.Text = NumericUpDown1.Value.ToString
        End If
    End Sub
```

Still remains question WHY is on (non nullable) numeric input control possible to input empty string. Answer for that will never come as I suppose.